# How to create a login form using a XAMPP database and C#?

Tags: c#, xampp

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM staff";
    string mySQLConnectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=workshopdb;sslmode=none";


    MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new 
    MySqlConnection(mySQLConnectionString);

    MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);

    databaseConnection.Open();

        MySqlDataReader myReader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        if (myReader.HasRows)           //checks whether the table is empty
        {
            while (myReader.Read())     //reads rows consequently
            {
                MessageBox.Show(myReader.GetString(0) + " " + myReader.GetString(1) + " " + myReader.GetString(3));
                //get strings(x) are columns of the table in the db
            }

        }

      databaseConnection.Close();
}
```

I used this code but It doesn't recognize the username and password that I entered. Instead of recognizing the entered user it shows all users in the database.

Comment: try like this    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "127.0.0.1";
conn_string.UserID = "sa";
conn_string.Password = "myPassword";
conn_string.Database = "myDatabase";

Answer (score 0):

In C#, building platform is .NET. Most of the time we can use MSSQL for DB activities. To Configure we can use MSSQL Server Express. XAMPP runs on Apache server. But for the .NET development we need IIS server. At your end arise conflicts. Do more research abourt what are you doing and get know about the dependent technologies